# iPod touch Song List

Tags: ipod-touch

I recently purchased an iPod touch and am very impressed with everything about it except one thing: I have a large collection of MP3s and on a lot of them the tags aren't quite right. For example, I have two albums by the same band but the names listed on them are just slightly different:

- A Day To Remember
- A Day to Remember

With iTunes and WMP this is not an issue - the albums are still grouped accordingly. With the iPod though, they show up as two different artists and it's driving me nuts. Does anyone know how to make it not care about the case?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure these are actually showing up as the same album in iTunes? Use Cover Flow to test.

The only way to fix this is to make sure that the album names are the same.

- In iTunes, select every track in the album, right click, then click "Get Info".

  [image]
- Fill in any of the tags that should be the same for every track (such as the Artist and album), and make sure the tick next to that text box is selected

  [image]
- Then just sync your iPod to iTunes.

Comment: You can also get a utility to clean up your metadata. I'm not familiar with the Windows software available for this other than TuneUp, which is paid, but there are free ones available. (I assume you're on Windows because of the WMP reference.)